# How implement a stream in c++/cx language

Tags: windows, c++11, stream, c++-cx

Hi I'm looking for an example which implements a stream in c++/cx,

to be clear this is the reference of class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

but no example how to implements in c++

thanks

Comment: You linked to the .NET Stream class.  That doesn't have anything to do with C++/CX.  WinRT stream classes live in the Windows::Storage::Stream namespace, there are many flavors.

Comment: sorry is c++/cx ms cpp extension

Comment: you can learn about C++/CX here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699871.aspx